# has many : through rails. how to get associated records from array of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, many-to-many

I've following models setup for has_many:through relationship

```
class StudyLevel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events_study_levels
  has_many :events, :through => :events_study_levels
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events_study_levels
  has_many :study_levels, :through => :events_study_levels
end

class EventsStudyLevels < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :study_level
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Now I want to have Events from a given array of study_levels. The one solution that I can think of is to find all the study_levels and then for every study level find all the events. But it is very inefficient. Can you please share a method that can help in achieving something like

```
Event.find_by_study_level_ids(study_level_ids_array)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access that information from `EventsStudyLevels`:

```
Event.where(id: EventStudyLevels.where(study_level_id: study_level_ids).pluck(:event_id))
```

Comment: I have eventually ended up solving before you posted the answer. Here is how I've done it.

    Event.joins(:study_levels).where("study_levels.id in (?) " ,study_level_ids).group("events.id")

Comment: Now my question is that which method will be more efficient. In Andrius solution, there will be 2 sql queries. In my method, there is one query but a join is used.

Comment: I suggest you benchmark which one is faster for your schema and data:

    Benchmark.measure { ...query1... }
    Benchmark.measure { ...query2... }

If the tables are small I suspect that the difference will be negligible.